# JAXB returns null when Xml does not include a tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am having a problem with JAXB and Unmarshalling the following XML

```
<ns2:ID entry-method="manual"> 123456789012345678
    <ns2:ID2>123456789012345678</ns2:ID2>
</ns2:ID>
```

I obtained the schema and using the the JAXB xjc tool it generated the following property definition:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "ID1",
    "ID2",
    "ID3"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ID")
public class ID {

@XmlElement(name = "ID1")
protected String id1;
@XmlElement(name = "ID2")
protected String id2;
@XmlElement(name = "ID3")
protected String id3;
@XmlAttribute(name = "entryMethod")
protected String entryMethod;

public String getId1() {
     return id1
}

public void setId1(String value) {
    this.id1 = value;

}

public String getId2() {
    return id2

}

public void setId2(String value) {
    this.id2 = value;
}

public String getId3() {
    return id3;
}

public void setId3(String value) {
    this.id3 = value;
}

public String getEntryMethod() {
    if (entryMethod == null) {
        return "swipe";
    } else {
        return entryMethod;
    }
}

public void setEntryMethod(String value) {
    this.entryMethod = value;
}
```

}

As you can see the device that is sending the XML does not include the ID1 tag it merely adds the ID1 data as the value of the root tag.  When Unmarshalling this Xml any calls to getID1 return null.  I am confused on what annotations to use to alter the class to support the data in the root tag to be assigned to the id1 field.

Any ideas on what annotation changes would make this work?

- Tim

Comment: If the XML tag is `<ns:ID1>` it will be stored in `ID.id1`, and if it is `<ns:ID2>` it will be stored in `ID.id2` - that's the whole point of using different tags. - If you don't care about the tags and want to receive any of ID1, ID2, ID99, FOO, BAR,...: it can be done, but why aren't you satisfied with the (precise) way it works? A field being null indicates the absence of an element or attribute, by design.

Comment: @laune I understand that but the specification for this states that if the entry-method attribute is set to swipe then the <id1> tag need not be present, the value can be assigned to the <id> tag. I cannot change that nor can I change the system that generates the xml I receive, and therefore I have to work within those constraints. Believe me when I say if I could change it I would. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct XML schema content (omitting namespace) for your XML:

```
<xs:element name="ID" type="IdType"/>

<xs:complexType name="IdType" mixed="true">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="id2" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="id3" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="entry-method" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

The sad consequence is that the generated class IdType contains

```
public List<Serializable> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
    }
    return this.content;
}
```

for containing the ID text child (children!) and all the ID element children. So, the processing of an ID might be something like:

```
JAXBElement<IdType> jbe =
        (JAXBElement<IdType>)u.unmarshal( new File( "mixed.xml" ) );
for( Object obj: jbe.getValue().getContent() ){
    System.out.println( obj.getClass() + " " + obj );
    if( obj instanceof String ){
        // text child (even the blank space
    } else if( obj instanceof JAXBElement ){
        // process an element child wrapped into JAXBElement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ID class should be ...

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ID")
public class ID {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ID3", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ID2", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "ID1", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "entry-method")
    protected String entryMethod;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getContent().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link String }
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the entryMethod property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getEntryMethod() {
        return entryMethod;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the entryMethod property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setEntryMethod(String value) {
        this.entryMethod = value;
    }

}
```

I tried this bean with this main method...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
   final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ID.class);

    final Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    final ID id = new ID();
    id.setEntryMethod("method");

    ObjectFactory o = new ObjectFactory();

    id.getContent().add("sample text");
    id.getContent().add(o.createIDID1("id1"));

    m.marshal(id, System.out);
}
```

The output generates is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ID entry-method="method">sample text
    <ID1>id1</ID1>
</ID>
```

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Comment: This code is only an example, therefore i put id1 value into <id1> :) ... your first problem is propOrder all attribute must be in lower case like your fields, the second were missing some ";", third I changed XmlAttribute entryMethod in entry-method :)

Comment: Appreciate the clarification, however it does not solve the issue that I cannot access the value assigned to the root tag <id>.

Comment: @milltj let me know if works fine else you put more informations in order to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

### Why You Are Getting Null

The XML you are unmarshalling does not match the XML Schema that you generated the object model from.

```
<ns2:ID entry-method="manual"> 123456789012345678
    <ns2:ID2>123456789012345678</ns2:ID2>
</ns2:ID>
```

### The Problem

When an element has both text and element it is said to have mixed content.  Your XML schema does not currently account for this.

### The Solution

Change the definition of the complex type corresponding to the `ID` element to have `mixed="true"`.  Then regenerate your JAXB model.

### Why You Won't Like The Solution

Since a type with mixed content scattered among the child elements you are going to get a very different JAXB model.  Essentially the class for `ID` is going to have one `List` property that contains all the content.  This is necessary to be able to find trip the XML.